# How to get highest value from xml element in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq, group-by

I need to get the highest `<WbDrillPermitNo>` ie 692753 from `<WBWellIdSegment>`.I wrote the code using linq as below but it's returning both `<WBWellIdSegment>` as result. Please help me get the maximum value.

```
 XDocument xml1 = XDocument.Load(File.FullName);

     List<XElement> segLists = xml1.Descendants("WBWellIdSegmentList").Descendants("WBWellIdSegment").Elements("WbDrillPermitNo").ToList();
     
     var result = segLists.GroupBy(i => i.Elements("WbDrillPermitNo"),
                  (i, group) => group.Single(x => x.Element("WbDrillPermitNo").Value == group.Max(y => 
                  y.Element("WbDrillPermitNo").Value)));
```

xml file

```
 <WBWellIdSegmentList>
          <WBWellIdSegment>     
            <WbOilLseNumber>07337</WbOilLseNumber>
            <WbOilWellNumber>1486W</WbOilWellNumber>
            <WbDrillPermitNo>370746</WbDrillPermitNo>       
          </WBWellIdSegment>
          <WBWellIdSegment>
            <WbOilLseNumber>07337</WbOilLseNumber>
            <WbOilWellNumber>1486</WbOilWellNumber>
            <WbDrillPermitNo>692753</WbDrillPermitNo>        
          </WBWellIdSegment>
    </WBWellIdSegmentList>
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're using GroupBy at all. Given the sample data you've provided, what exact result are you looking for? You might find the `MaxBy` method in the MoreLINQ useful, by the way... and you'll definitely want to convert the permit number into an integer rather than using string comparisons (as your code does right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return max value (assume that the value is of type integer)

```
wellBore.Descendants("WbDrillPermitNo").Select(e => int.Parse(e.Value)).Max();
```

To return element `<WBWellIdSegment>` with max value from `<WbDrillPermitNo>` you can use `Aggregate` method

```
var segmentWithMaxNumber = wellBore.Descendants("WBWellIdSegment")
   .Select(e => (Element: e, Number: int.Parse(e.Element("WbDrillPermitNo").Value)))
   .Aggregate((max, e) => e.Number > max.Number ? e : max, max => max.Element);
```

Comment: It should be `int.Parse` or `Int32.Parse`. But this does not do what the OP requires because it gets the max Id, not the element that bears the max Id

Comment: @AluanHaddad, maybe, but OP says: _Please help me get the **maximum value**_ -;)